# Plotting 2D equation with infinite sum

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I'm trying to plot the following equation (let's call it "Equation 1"):

[image: equation 1]

This is the code I'm testing:

```
clear all;

xl=0; xr=1;                 % x domain [xl,xr]
J = 10;                     % J: number of division for x
dx = (xr-xl) / J;           % dx: mesh size
tf = 0.1;                   % final simulation time
Nt = 60;                    % Nt: number of time steps
dt = tf/Nt/4; 

x = xl : dx : xr;              % generate the grid point
u_ex = zeros(J+1,Nt);

for n = 1:Nt
    t = n*dt;         % current time

    for j=1:J+1
      xj = xl + (j-1)*dx;
      suma = zeros(100 , 1);

      for k= 1:100
        suma(k) = 4/(((2*k-1)^2) *pi*pi);
        suma(k) = suma(k) * exp(-((2*k-1)^2) *pi*pi*t) * cos(2*k-1)*pi*xj;
      end 

      m = sum(suma);      
      u_ex(j, n)= 0.5 - m;

    end
end

tt = dt : dt : Nt*dt;

figure(1)
surf(x,tt, u_ex');     % 3-D surface plot
xlabel('x')
ylabel('t')
zlabel('u')
```

The problem is that all I get is a flat surface:

[image]

Equation 1 is suppossed to be the solution of the following parabolic partial differential equation with boundary values:

[image]

And after getting the numerical solution, it should look like this:

[image]

This plot gets the right values at the boundaries x = 0 and x = 1. The plot of Equation 1 doesn't have those values at the boundaries.

My complete .m code (that plots both the numerical solution and Equation 1) is:

```
clear all;                  % clear all variables in memory

xl=0; xr=1;                 % x domain [xl,xr]
J = 10;                     % J: number of division for x
dx = (xr-xl) / J;           % dx: mesh size
tf = 0.1;                   % final simulation time
Nt = 60;                    % Nt: number of time steps
dt = tf/Nt/4; 

mu = dt/(dx)^2; 

if mu > 0.5         % make sure dt satisy stability condition
    error('mu should < 0.5!')
end

% Evaluate the initial conditions
x = xl : dx : xr;              % generate the grid point

% store the solution at all grid points for all time steps
u = zeros(J+1,Nt);
u_ex = zeros(J+1,Nt);

% Find the approximate solution at each time step
for n = 1:Nt
    t = n*dt;         % current time
    % boundary condition at left side
    gl = 0;
    % boundary condition at right side
    gr = 0;

    for j=2:J    
      if n==1    % first time step
         u(j,n) = j;
      else            % interior nodes
         u(j,n)=u(j,n-1) + mu*(u(j+1,n-1) - 2*u(j,n-1) + u(j-1,n-1));
      end
    end

    u(1,n) = gl;   % the left-end point
    u(J+1,n) = gr; % the right-end point 

    % calculate the analytic solution 
    for j=1:J+1
      xj = xl + (j-1)*dx;

      suma = zeros(100 , 1);

      for k= 1:100
        suma(k) = 4/(((2*k-1)^2) *pi*pi);
        suma(k) = suma(k) * exp(-((2*k-1)^2) *pi*pi*t) * cos(2*k-1)*pi*xj;
      end 

      m = sum(suma);

      u_ex(j, n)= 0.5 - m;

    end
end

% Plot the results
tt = dt : dt : Nt*dt;
figure(1)
colormap(gray);     % draw gray figure
surf(x,tt, u');     % 3-D surface plot
xlabel('x')
ylabel('t')
zlabel('u')
title('Numerical solution of 1-D parabolic equation')

figure(2)
surf(x,tt, u_ex');     % 3-D surface plot
xlabel('x')
ylabel('t')
zlabel('u')
title('Analytic solution of 1-D parabolic equation')

maxerr=max(max(abs(u-u_ex))),
```

The code is taken from the book "Computational Partial Differential Equations Using MATLAB" by Yi-Tung Chen, Jichun Li, chapter 2, exercise 3.

In short: I'm not asking about the differential equation or the boundary problem, I want to know is: Why am I getting a flat surface when plotting Equation 1? Am I missing a parenthesis?
I do not want to use the symsum function because it never stop the script execution and I want to learn how to plot Equation 1 with no using symsum.

I've tested this code with Matlab R2008b and Octave 4.2.1. I got the same results (even with sums of 1000, 10000 and 50000 terms in the `for loop` with the `k` variable).

**Edit!**
Thanks, Steve!

I was missing a couple of parenthesis near the cosine, the right code is:

```
clear all;                  % clear all variables in memory

xl=0; xr=1;                 % x domain [xl,xr]
J = 10;                     % J: number of division for x
dx = (xr-xl) / J;           % dx: mesh size
tf = 0.1;                   % final simulation time
Nt = 60;                    % Nt: number of time steps
dt = tf/Nt/4; 

mu = dt/(dx)^2; 

if mu > 0.5         % make sure dt satisy stability condition
    error('mu should < 0.5!')
end

% Evaluate the initial conditions
x = xl : dx : xr;              % generate the grid point

% store the solution at all grid points for all time steps
u = zeros(J+1,Nt);
u_ex = zeros(J+1,Nt);

% Find the approximate solution at each time step
for n = 1:Nt
    t = n*dt;         % current time
    % boundary condition at left side
    gl = 0;
    % boundary condition at right side
    gr = 0;

    for j=2:J    
      if n==1    % first time step
         u(j,n) = j;
      else            % interior nodes
         u(j,n)=u(j,n-1) + mu*(u(j+1,n-1) - 2*u(j,n-1) + u(j-1,n-1));
      end
    end

    u(1,n) = gl;   % the left-end point
    u(J+1,n) = gr; % the right-end point 

    % calculate the analytic solution 
    for j=1:J+1
      xj = xl + (j-1)*dx;

      suma = zeros(1000 , 1);

      for k= 1:1000
        suma(k) = 4/(((2*k-1)^2) *pi*pi);
        suma(k) *= exp(-((2*k-1)^2) *pi*pi*t) * cos((2*k-1)*pi*xj);
      end 

      m = sum(suma);

      u_ex(j, n)= 0.5 - m;

    end
end

% Plot the results
tt = dt : dt : Nt*dt;
figure(1)
colormap(gray);     % draw gray figure
surf(x,tt, u');     % 3-D surface plot
xlabel('x')
ylabel('t')
zlabel('u')
title('Numerical solution of 1-D parabolic equation')

figure(2)
surf(x,tt, u_ex');     % 3-D surface plot
xlabel('x')
ylabel('t')
zlabel('u')
title('Analytic solution of 1-D parabolic equation')
```

Now my Equation 1 looks much better:

[image: much better]

Also Steve was right when pointing out that my numerical solution may be wrong. I didn't notice that the boundary values are for the derivatives of my function, not the actual values of the function. I'll ask my teacher about this.

**Edit2!**
Ok, I got it. To calculate the derivatives at the boundaries you have to use hint 2.21 in the same book:

[image]

```
% hint 2.21 given by the book
% it is better to calculate the boundary values after calculating the inner points inside the for j = 1:m loop because you will need them:
u(1, n) = u(2, n) - dx * gl; % the left-end point
u(J+1,n) = u(J, n) + dx * gr; % the right-end point
```

Now my numerical solution looks like my analytic solution :D

Matlab R2008b can't recognize the `*=` operator that Octave does. I'm not tested this operator in other versions of Matlab because I'm too poor.

Yvon: I think the analytical solution formula comes from the real part of a Fourier expansion, but authors don't tell how they got it.

Comment: For one I suspect that your equation should read `cos((2*k-1)*pi*x)` instead of `cos(2*k-1)*pi*x`.

Comment: Secondly I don't trust the numerical solution you're giving, which seems to obey `u(1,t)=0` instead of `u_x(1,t)=0`.

Comment: You got it right for the boundary conditions (spacial derivative terms). I suspect the initial condition you applied was wrong. From the solution I guess you used Fourier series of a sawtooth wave, right?

Comment: @Yvon you're right. I re-read the exercise and I have to apply an extra method for derivatives in the boundaries. I do not know where the solution comes from, it is given by book's author for comparison with the numerical solution.

Comment: First of all, I'm not an expert in PDE. From the BC I was able to derive the cosine terms in the expansion, but the time part is still unknown. Trying to apply Fourier series on the IC did not help me any further. It looked so weird to me that the IC has a `x` term on the right, which gives an infinite expansion term in the solution, independent of that cosine term from BC.